# Is ibdump in Mellanox OFED 2 supported in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: traffic-shaping, infiniband, mellanox

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I have Mellanox Technologies MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3] HCAs. I was able to pass all the tests like ibping and ib_rdma_lat.
Now I'm running MPI tests to verify that InfiniBand is working.
How can I actually see that there is traffic going through the HCA's port?

I've tried to execute the ibdump utility (from all the RPMs that were in the download). But it fails. with this:

```
root@node3:~/ibdump-1.0.5-4-rpms/ibdump-1.0.5-4.x86_64-rhel6/usr/bin# ./ibdump
 ------------------------------------------------
 IB device                      : "mlx4_0"       
 IB port                        : 1              
 Dump file                      : sniffer.pcap   
 Sniffer WQEs (max burst size)  : 4096           
 ------------------------------------------------

Initiating resources ...                         
searching for IB devices in host                 
Warning: memory access to device mlx4_0 failed: Input/output error.
Warning: Fallback on IO: much slower, and unsafe if device in use.
-E- Failed to open mst device mlx4_0: No such file or directory   
-E- failed to create resources
```

But there is actually the mlx4_0 device. As I said all the tests from the infiniband-diags package are passed.

Is ibdump supported in MLNX_OFED 2 in Ubuntu 14.04? If no then what alternatives can I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mellanox answered my question http://community.mellanox.com/thread/1741.

The answer is that there is actually no `ibdump` for ConnetX-3 adapters for Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the mst device because you don't have the `mft` package installed. Try to install the `mft` package, and start the mst module (you can use the `mst start` command to do that).